# Sylius demo broken cause of new channel

Tags: sylius

As mentioned in the title: http://demo.sylius.org/ throws a 500 Error cause of a new channel which is disabled.

If you go to http://demo.sylius.org/admin/channels/ (I guess the guys working with it know how to login) you will see the "new" disabled channel. If you remove it, the http://demo.sylius.org/ will run again.

To make this a question: How to create a new Channel or is there a stable Sylius version?